# Queuing API message from JavaScript (or Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a mobile application using Cordova with AgularJS that sends a message to an API. I am supporting HTML5 browsers only.

The API call doesn't need to be instant, it can happen after sometime. So, it is fine if the network is down/slow or the API is down, but the important thing is that the call will happen at some stage. No feedback on the client is needed other than the message is received.

**Is there any library (pure JavaScript or Angular JS) that does that? Say call the library and the library will queue the message and deliver it at some stage or try again after a set amount of time until the message is delivered?**

If there is no ready-made library, then do you have any best practices of how to achieve this?

N.B. If the browser is restarted, the messages should be still in the queue (so memory storage may not be appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if it is just about chaining requests and putting them somewhere in an object, you could use angularJS's $q Service:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

You can also chain these promises, a nice how-to (old...):
http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/

If you also work with the location service from angularJS, you can even resolve all this data before the app gets loaded, but I guess that's not a requirement.

Comment: I added a note that I want to support restarting the browser, I am not sure that this works after restarting the browser, does it?

Comment: If you need a state, you could combine the example with local storage

Answer (score 1):

You could use [bluebird.js](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) to achieve your desired functionality. E.g.

```
function a(params) {
    let p = return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        yourLibraryThatCallsYourAPI(params, result => {
            // Resolves when ever your API sends reply.
            resolve(result);
        }, error => {
            reject(new Error(error));
        });
    }

    // After 5 seconds, try again.
    p.timeout(5000).then(result => {
        console.info(result);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error(e.message);

        return a(params);
    });

    return p;
}

...

a();
```

Comment: Is this a persistent storage (like in localStorage or WebSQL)? As I am looking for a permanent (well, semi-permanent) one in case the application is restarted.

Comment: If you need a state, you could combine the example with local storage